# Embed PNG or BMP VS JPG or GIF images in ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, mime, coldfusion-11

I have tried different image formats for emailing.
JPG and GIF (with transparency) are working fine.

I also tried [this scenario](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1220-coldfusion-cfmailparam-s-new-content-attribute-is-awesome.htm) and it works perfectly.
However it works only if the picture is JPG or GIF.
PNG or BMP files are not embedding properly and are sent as an attachment, and not as mail content as declared by `contentID` inside the cfmailparam.

Here is the short sample extracted from CFC file.

```
<cfcomponent>
<!--- function to send email--->
<cffunction name = "send" returntype = "any">

<cfmail
to="abc@aaa.com"
from="def@bbb.com"
subject="test msg.">        
<cfmailpart type="html">
    TEST MESSAGE. <br />
    <img src="cid:embedded_image1" /><br />
    <img src="cid:embedded_image2" /><br />
    END OF MESSAGE.

    <cfset obImage1 = ImageNew("http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/pnglogo-blk-sml1.png") />
    <cfmailparam file="image1.png" contentid="embedded_image1" content="#obImage1#" disposition="inline" />

    <cfset obImage2 = ImageNew("http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/rose_sparkle.gif") />
    <cfmailparam file="image2.gif" contentid="embedded_image2" content="#obImage2#" disposition="inline" />

</cfmailpart>
</cfmail>

</cffunction>
```

I am suspecting I am missing something to be declared, like MIME or something similar.
Can someone try and see why GIF is working but PNG is failing?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is what I found interesting:

**Case 1**

- Add **type="image/png"**

The image is included in the email. However the transparency becomes black (like rewriting).

```
<cfset obImage1 = ImageNew("http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/pnglogo-blk-sml1.png") />
<cfmailparam file="image1.png" 
   contentid="embedded_image1" 
   content="#obImage1#" 
   type="image/png" 
   disposition="inline" />
```

**Case 2**

- Add **type="image/png"**
- Use a URL instead of a path in **file=".."**
- Remove **content="#obImage1#"**

Image is kept as is, transparency is kept too. However the filename is the existing file and I cannot rename it because it got the value from *content*. But at least it works.

```
<cfmailparam file="http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/pnglogo-blk-sml1.png" 
   contentid="embedded_image1" 
   type="image/png" 
   disposition="inline" />
```

Now here is the other problem: **How do I make the file name a custom name?**

Comment: For grins, have you tried using both the "file" and "filename" attributes with Case 1?

Comment: file and filename produce different results. also it is different if the source file is coming from a local storage like cf server shared folder or from external web address. case 1 and case 2 are working on both cases, it is just the issues experienced with file names (case 2) and (image rewriting case 1). Or maybe i am missing something. I would be glad if someone could point the right solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand. However, it doesn't seem like adobe supports changing the file name, so I'm trying to see if you can "trick" it by using both "file" and "filename='theNameYouWant.png'" in Case 1 (only).  (IIRC, it won't work with Case 2).